# Apply SQL condition only to selected group

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working right now with a project with a Graph and a Table. Each of these two has different groupings, so Graph data can be grouped by `A` and `B`, while the Table can be grouped by `A` and `C`. So the approach I chose to handle this is having a separate SQL call for each, which is the easier path, I believe.

Now the problem is we have a filter function, e.g. `cost <= 85`. There's no problem with it on the Tables data, but for the Graph Data since it's grouped by `Date`, the condition will apply for each data on each date.

**Filter 1**

`cost <= 85`

[image]

**Filter 2**

`cost < 80`

[image]

As you can see in the filter 2, the data on the table is gone since the cost is not `< 80`, but on the graph it's still there since each of the point values are lesser than 80.

SQL Query:

`SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE cost < 80 GROUP BY category, brand, date`.

This sounds stupid but my question is, is it possible to apply the conditions for group `category` and `brand` only, while it is still grouped by `date`? One route I'm thinking of is to apply the conditions in the `PHP` side. But if there are other solutions, I'm happy to hear.

Comment: I don't understand you question  .. try add  a proper data (not image) sample and the expetced  result  ..

Comment: Where are your other queries ? Without it we can't help you.